# Is $G-e$ $(k-1)$-connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ is a $k$-connected graph and $e$ is an edge of G, then $G-e$ is $(k-1)$-connected.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know Menger's Theorem yet?

Comment: Not yet. I need to use connectivity concepts to prove this.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose, for contradiction, that $G-e$ is not $(k-1)$-connected. Then there exists a set of $(k-2)$ vertices $V$ such that $(G-e)-V$ is disconnected. Now, think about where this edge $e$ can possibly live. Either it's incident to a vertex in $V$ or not. If it is, there is a clear contradiction (think about how $(G-e)-V$ and $G-V$ compare). If it isn't, then $e$ is an edge of $G-V$. Since $G$ is $k$-connected, $G-V$ is connected, but by assumption, $(G-e)-V$ is not. So, removal of $e$ from $G-V$ disconnects the graph. This should lead you to a contradiction. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see the contradiction yet. I must be missing something.

Comment: The first or the second one?

Comment: Unfortunately either. I don't see it yet.

Comment: I can see it now!

Comment: For the first one, remember that when you do "$G-V$" you remove from $G$ not only all the vertices in $V$, but also all edges incident to vertices in $V$. So, if $e$ is incident to a vertex in $V$, it gets removed in $G-V$. So, $(G-e)-V$ and $G-V$ should be the same graph. For the second less obvious contradiction, the edge $e$ connects two disjoint components of $(G-e)-V$, so what does that imply about the connectivity of $G-V$?

Comment: For the second contradiction, does that imply that $e$ is a bridge?

Comment: Yes exactly, which also implies something about its incident vertices...

Comment: The vertex incident with the bridge $e$ is a cut-vertex if and only if the deg $v \geq 2$.